# RestException is not a valid phone number on Twilio trial account

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-sdk

I use `twilio/sdk` package, with the following code.

```
$sid = "AC3###############";
$token = "100################";

$from = $to = "+628********99";

$otp = rand(1111111, 9999999);

$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
$message = $client
  ->messages
  ->create($to, [
     'from' => $to, 
     'body' => 'OTP code : ' . $otp
  ])
```

This is the error that I got

`Twilio\Exceptions\RestException  [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number +628********99 is not a valid phone number.`

What did I do wrong ?
How can I use my trial account to send trial sms?

FYI the number I used is a verified number in Twilio and country origin is Indonesia +62.

Answer (score 0):

The line `$token = '100################;` is missing it's closing single quote. Could that be the reason?

PS: It's hard to build SMS OTP right because of fraud schemes like [SMS Traffic Pumping Fraud](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/8360406023067-SMS-Traffic-Pumping-Fraud). [Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) has built-in protection against these risks.

Comment: no that is not the case, i will adjust my question , thanks for notice it

Comment: is it because i use non twilio number ? because the number is already verified before.

Comment: Mhhh, could be. Can you try it with a Twilio number?

Comment: are there free twilio number available ? at least for testing to send to my own number

Comment: No free ones but you could try to use a string as a sender to use an alphanumeric sender id if your country is supported without pre-registration https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID